# React/Redux: Is there a way to clear react date-picker when it's incorporated with redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Essentially I have a react date picker incorporated as a redux form field in my form. I allow the user to clear the entire form by using redux-form reset prop. It's odd because the datepicker is recognized in my form data but when I try to clear the entire page it is the only field that doesn't clear.

this.props.reset
this.props.change

My datepicker:

```
const CustomInput = React.forwardRef((props, refs) => {
    const inputProps = props.inputProps;
    inputProps.input.onChange(props.value);
    return (
        <div className="input-button">
            <FormattedTextInput
                {...inputProps}
                ref={refs}
                onFocus={props.onFocus}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                helpText={<span aria-hidden="true">YYYY-MM-DD | HH:MM</span>}
            />
        </div>
    );
});

CustomInput.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    inputProps: PropTypes.object
};

const DateTimePicker = props => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
    const ref = React.createRef();

    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
            minDate={moment()}
            customInput={<CustomInput inputProps={props} ref={ref} />}
            showTimeSelect
            disabledKeyboardNavigation
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={15}
            timeCaption="time"
            isClearable
            dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
        />
    );
};

export default DateTimePicker;
```

My field:

```
<Field
                                className="usaa-input"
                                component={DateTimePicker}
                                label="Future Date"
                                name="futureDate"
                                validate={[required, validDateTimeFormat]}
                                formatting="9999-99-99 99:99"
                            />
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets it value from the startDate useState. 
UseEffect is similiar to componentWillUnmount of class.

You should use useEffect to reset startDate value when this function is no longer mounted.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setStartDate(null);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I noticed the parent’s state gets cleared because the field validation gets reset but you can still see the date because internal state isn't being reset.